# Compete direct sum

Tags: modules

If $R$ is a ring and $A$ and $B$ are $R$-modules, then I'm familiar with the definitions of the external and internal direct sum. But I wonder what is the definition of a **complete sum**. Is it different from the aforementioned types of sums above?

Thanks in advance.

The citation below is taken out of a paper not a book.

[image]

Comment: Google search doesn't turn up the term, so citation needed.

Comment: I edited the post @EricTowers